# improve the accuracy of my model buid with keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, numbers, prediction

I'm trying to build ANN architecture to predict sickness rate. I'm actually stuck in 40% accuracy, I'm new in machine learning and I tried several tips like changing the optimzer, the layer node number and the dropout value without any improving.
So could you guys help me with some advice.

the x array is composed of 10 columns

the y array is only one column the sickness rate

here is my model

```py
def build_dropout_model(rate):
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(10,input_shape=(10,)))
  model.add(Dropout(rate))  
  model.add(Dense(256,kernel_constraint=NonNeg(),activation="relu"))
  model.add(Dense(256,kernel_constraint=NonNeg(),activation="relu"))
  model.add(Dense(128,kernel_constraint=NonNeg(),activation="relu"))
  model.add(Dense(1,activation="sigmoid"))
  model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_absolute_error',metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model
model = build_dropout_model(0.2)
history = model.fit(xtr,ytr,epochs=1000,verbose=2)
```

```py
loss, acc=model.evaluate(xtst,ytst)
```

[image]

and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a regression model, not a classification model, so you should be using "linear" in your output layer.

```
model.add(Dense(1,activation="linear"))
```

Comment: thanks @johnny1995 for your help but the accuracy passed to zero with this modification